# Download images and ZIP them through PHP

Tags: php, javascript, zip

I have a couple of URLs that link to images and I want to be able to make a .zip file with those images. Users can download their own images, basically.

The images are not on my server, is there a way to zip these files in a way that each user uses their own bandwidth?

If not, what is the best solution to this problem? (PHP or Javascript)

Edit: Why the 2 downvotes? I'm not asking for code. 
I have 2 questions:
1) Can I download images and ZIP them without using my servers bandwidth?
2) If no, what's the best solution.

Comment: curl, save them, zip them and add to header

Comment: So what's your exact question? You're describing several features (grab a remote file, create a ZIP archive, provide a download, keep track of consumed bandwidth per user...). If you are stuck in all of them, you should consider hiring a professional. This is not a site to get finished code for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with JS by using ajax to download images ([here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?249163-Getting-binary-data.-Lost-of-128-chars) are some thoughts about downloading binary data using ajax) and some JS ZIP library (for example http://stuartk.com/jszip/) to pack data - then no server bandwidth will be used.

Another possibility is to download images to server (for example using [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)), zip them (for example using [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class) and send to client - this solution uses server bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks! So it's just a matter of making sure that JS ZIP can reach the retrieved AJAX data..

Answer (score 7):

1.To download images, If http://example.com/image.php hoding a image as test.jpg

a) If you have allow_url_fopen set to true:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/tempfolder/test.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

b) Else use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/tempfolder/test.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

2.To zip all files, you can use [ziparchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) to create zip.

```
$files = array('test.jpg', 'test1.jpg');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

3.To stream zip file use following lines,

```
$zipfilename = 'file.zip';
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename));
```